# Swift Upload Multiple Files with associated parameters to ASP.NET Method

Tags: c#, ios, asp.net, swift, alamofire

I am trying to upload multiple files with parameters to an ASP.NET Method, the ASP.NET method is expecting a List of a class, I am able to send what the ASP.NET is expecting but my HttpPostedFile is null :( My question is what am I doing wrong on the iOS side? Here is my iOS function written in swift:

```
func saveQAPhotos(_ cellHolder: Array<PhotoClass>, completion: @escaping (_ result: String) -> Void)
    {


        //Define Array of Dictionary

        var jsonArrayOfDictionaries = [[AnyHashable: Any]]()

        //For each item in the cellHolder

        for i in 0..<cellHolder.count {

            //Define Dictionary for grading data

            var jsonDict = [AnyHashable: Any]()

            jsonDict["job"] = cellHolder[i].job

            jsonDict["imageBytes"] = cellHolder[i].photo!.base64EncodedString().addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)

            jsonDict["createdBy"] = appDelegate.username

            jsonDict["itemId"] = cellHolder[i].itemId

            jsonArrayOfDictionaries.append(jsonDict)

            jsonDict = [AnyHashable: Any]()

        }

        let jsonData: Data? = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonArrayOfDictionaries, options: .prettyPrinted)

        let urlComponents = NSURLComponents(string: webservice + "uploadQAImage");

        urlComponents?.user = appDelegate.username;

        urlComponents?.password = appDelegate.password;

        let url = urlComponents?.url;

        var request = URLRequest(url: url!)

        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        request.setValue("multipart/form-data", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        request.httpBody = jsonData

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {
            (data, response, error) in

            if(error != nil){

                completion((error?.localizedDescription)!)

            }else{

                let responseString = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)

                OperationQueue.main.addOperation({

                    completion(responseString!)

                })
            }

        }).resume()
    }
```

and here is some of my ASP.NET method:

```
public string uploadQAImage(List<FileUploadClass> fileUploads) {

    for (int i = 0; i < fileUploads.Count; i++) {
        HttpPostedFile hfc = fileUploads[i].imageBytes;
    }

}
```

hfc is always null when I send it the iOS Data of the file in question. I do have Alamofire installed on my app, I could use that, but could I use the upload method to send what ASP.NET is expecting?

Here is my model

```
public class FileUploadClass
    {
        public string job { get; set; }
        public string createdBy { get; set; }
        public HttpPostedFile imageBytes { get; set; }
        public int itemId { get; set; }

    }
```

and here is my swift class

```
class PhotoClass: NSObject {

    var job: String?

    var photo: Data?

    var itemId: Int?

    init(job: String?, photo: Data, itemId: Int?)
    {
        self.job = job

        self.photo = photo

        self.itemId = itemId
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you please add you action declaration with classes it accepts? Like `public ActionResult MyAction(Model model)` and code of `Model` class

Comment: I updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According [to the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httppostedfile?view=netframework-4.7.2), the expected format is MIME `multipart/form-data` for `HttpPostedFile`:

> Files are uploaded in MIME multipart/form-data format. By default, all
>   requests, including form fields and uploaded files, larger than 256 KB
>   are buffered to disk, rather than held in server memory.

You are sending some sort of JSON-formatted POST body and calling it multipart, but instead you need to actually send multi-part MIME.  The RFC describing multi-part MIME format is here:  https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html

Unfortunately, I haven't used any of the many libraries that will do this encoding for you.  This one looks easy to use:  https://github.com/Fyrts/Multipart  -- here's an example:

```
import Multipart

let fileContents = try! Data(contentsOf: URL(string: "/Users/user/Desktop/document.pdf")!)

var message = Multipart(type: .formData)
message.append(Part.FormData(name: "message", value: "See attached file."))
message.append(Part.FormData(name: "file", fileData: fileContents, fileName: "document.pdf", contentType: "application/pdf"))

var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://example.com")!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.setMultipartBody(message)

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    print(data, response, error)
}.resume()
```